# Constraints on gcc / glibc versions between build and run

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

Probably a basic question but I did not manage to find a clear answer to it:

Let's say I am compiling a code (with some parts in C) on a build server and run it on a different server. The build server has gcc version X and glibc version Y. What are the constraints on the gcc and glibc versions on the run server, in order for my code to run properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few constraints:

- application is compiled using the same architecture, e.g., `x86_64`
- glibc should be at the same revision or later on the run-server

Comment: "glibc should be at the same revision or later on the run-server" is a useful rule of thumb, but it's not strictly accurate: the required version of glibc depends on the exact symbols used in the binary produced on the build-server. For example, [`miller`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/miller) only needs `glibc` 2.14 on `amd64` even though it was compiled with 2.22 (yesterday).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "revision" ? Are glibc-2.17.55 and glibc-2.17.106 considered as two different revisions ?

Comment: glibc uses versioned-symbols, and a later revision of glibc will include symbols using both the newest version and older versions.  So an application linked with a given revision level of glibc will run with that revision -- or later.  Odds are that compiling linking with a newer revision will pick up newer symbol versions. It's been that way since around 2000.

Comment: `strings /lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC` and `strings /lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` on both build and run servers to find highest supported **common** version of C and C++ libraries.